# init ramdisk module loading gives out of memory error

Tags: kernel, compiling

I have a ALIENWARE laptop with specs as:
CPU: Core-i7
NVIDIA: GTX 1060
RAM : 16 GB
Storage: 240 GB SSD and 1TB HDD

I have installed the ubuntu with kernel as 4.13.0 and tried to manually download latest kernel version linux-4 .14 and compiled with existing .config file.

I downloaded the kernel from kernel.org. 
Following step I followed to build:

1. uncompressed the kernel into `/usr/src/custom_kernel/`
2. copied c`onfig-$(uname -r)-generic` into `/usr/src/custom_kernel/`
3. renamed it as `.config`
4. > make oldconfig
5. > make menuconfig

   (changed the kernel name string only) and saved.
6. In all the prompted option in step-4 I have opted as default.
7. > make -j 8
8. > make modules_install
9. > make install

I build the kernel and installed it.

Now while reboot, it shows loading of init ramdisk.

Then show error: out of memory.

What is the issue.

Comment: If you're trying to boot that kernel you download from who know where and compile who know how, that IS the issue.

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Comment: Not supported here and off topic.